# Import IntelliJ code style into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

I would like to know if it's possible and how to export my IntelliJ code style settings and import them into Eclipse. I know it's possible from Eclipse into IntelliJ but I want the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

You must **set up manually** in Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked around but unfortunately I have not found any plugin to Eclipse that could do that. It's probably because of the way that IDEA's code style is stored in xml and because of variety of options that are not available in Eclipse.

Comment: Not exactly, because many options in both IDEs are similar. It certainly is possible to share great part of the code style settings - this is exactly what `Eclipse Code Formatter` for IntelliJ does. But someone's time & effort is needed.